# jQuery: How to override pseudo style?

Tags: jquery

So here's the summary

CSS:

```
input[type="text"]:focus{background:blue;}
.error{background:red;}
```

Javascript:

```
if(error){ $('#elementid').focus().addClass('error');
```

Problem:

The field goes red then goes blue immediately and stays blue when it is
 in focus.

How do I make the 'error' class take precedence, when the javascript executes and the focus goes to the 'elementid' field and not the :focus class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give `.error` more specificity, like this:

```
input[type="text"].error{background:red;}​
//or if shared:
.error, input[type="text"].error{background:red;}​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6sNcx/), with the same level of specificity, `error` will win because it's declared later in the CSS.

Comment: The second approach was more appropriate for me as it's a shared style. Thanks for the quick response.

Also, thanks for that link. Great tool!